# In XML using XSLT, Copy few elements and change value of others

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration name="abc">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="1">A</Property>
        <Property name="2">B</Property>
        <Property name="3">C</Property>
        <Property name="4">D</Property>
        <Property name="5">E</Property>
        <Property name="6">F</Property>
    </Properties>
</Configuration>
```

I want to change the value of property names 1 and 2 only and for others to stay as it is.

Here is the code which I am using, but it is removing all other element and giving me value of only 1 element in my output file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Configuration/Properties/Property[@name='1']" />
        <xsl:template match="Configuration/Properties">
        <xsl:element name="Properties">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(Property/@name='1')">
                <xsl:element name="Property" >
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'1'"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'INFO'"/>
                </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your `xsl:stylesheet` element is broken. You are missing the namespace declaration and the closing `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you need to define all of these. Just copy whole and update those particular values.

```
<xsl:template match="Configuration/Properties/Property[@name='1']/text()">'Your value'</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Configuration/Properties/Property[@name='2']/text()">'Your 2nd value'</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, What was the mistake I was doing?

Comment: @conal-tuohy Defined it very well, Thank you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74135280/11195302 refer this.

Answer (score 1):

There were quite a few things wrong with your stylesheet.

- Firstly, it was not well-formed XML; it was missing a closing `>` on the stylesheet element, and also the `xsl` namespace declaration.
- You had a template to match `Property` elements whose `name` attribute equalled `1`, and do nothing (i.e. to remove such a `Property`), but that template was never actually invoked, because of the other template that matched the `Properties` element.
- The template that matched the `Properties` element had a `choose` child containing a `when` which would check to see if the `Properties` element had a `Property` child element with a `name` attribute whose value was `1`, and if it did, the template would create a new `Property` element whose `name` attribute was also `1`, and give it the content `INFO`. The `choose` element had no other child elements (other `when` or `otherwise` elements) so in the case that the `Properties` element did not have a `Property/@name='1'`, the template would do nothing, effectively ignoring all the `Property` child elements.

I suspect you have some misconceptions about the way XSLT works and I'd recommend some background reading to get a more solid understanding.

My example shows a simple way to replace the text values.

I've retained your identity template which has the effect of copying everything which isn't matched by a more specific template. Then I added a template to match the text node inside the `Property` element whose `name` attribute was `1`. That text node is of course the node containing the value `A`. The template then outputs a new text node `INFO`. Note that if this template did not exist, the identity template would have matched that text node (`A`), instead, and would have copied it.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="
        Configuration/Properties/Property[@name='1']/text()
    ">INFO</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, What was the mistake I was doing?

Comment: I've expanded my answer with a detailed explanation

Comment: What if I have to put one more check if 6 is present or not, If not I want to create it. But while doing so with the below code it is taking only one template

<xsl:template match="Configuration/Properties">
<xsl:element name="Properties">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="not(Property/@name='6')">
<xsl:copy-of select="Property" />
<xsl:element name="Property" >
<xsl:attribute name="name">
<xsl:value-of select="'6'"/>
<xsl:element name="Property" >
<xsl:attribute name="name">
<xsl:value-of select="'6'"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="abc"/>

Comment: It's hard to follow your comment, I'm afraid. You could edit your question or ask a new question.

Comment: I asked another question, Please help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74258299/in-xml-using-xslt-copy-few-elements-change-value-of-others-and-insert-one-if-n