# In XML using XSLT, Copy few elements, change value of others and insert one if not present

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration name="abc">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="1">A</Property>
        <Property name="2">B</Property>
        <Property name="3">C</Property>
        <Property name="4">D</Property>
        <Property name="5">E</Property>
        <Property name="6">F</Property>
    </Properties>
</Configuration>
```

I want to change the value of property names 1 and 2 only and for others to stay as it is, And I want to check if 6 is present or not, If not I want to create it. But while doing so with the below code, I think it is taking only one template which is broadly initialised

Here is the code which I am using,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Configuration/Properties/Property[@name='level']/text()">INFO</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Configuration/Properties/Property[@name='Workflow_level']/text()">INFO</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Configuration/Properties/Property[@name='SVE_level']/text()">INFO</xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="Configuration/Properties">
        <xsl:element name="Properties">
                <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="not(Property/@name='6')">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="Property" />
                                        <xsl:element name="Property" >
                                                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="'6'"/>
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="abc"/>
                                        </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="Property" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What's going on here is that your template which matches `Configuration/Properties` is using `xsl:copy` to explicitly *copy* all the child elements of `Properties`, and additionally inserting the `Property` 6 if necessary, but it doesn't call `apply-templates`, so the *other* templates never have a chance to match anything.

I've reworked it so that rather than using `xsl:copy` to copy the other `Property` elements, it calls `xsl:apply-templates` instead; the result is that the other templates are invoked, and will copy those `Property` elements, and also change their text content where appropriate.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <!-- copy everything unchanged except where overridden by the templates below -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- replace the text content of certain named Property elements -->
   <xsl:template match="Configuration/Properties/Property[@name='level']/text()">INFO</xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Configuration/Properties/Property[@name='Workflow_level']/text()">INFO</xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Configuration/Properties/Property[@name='SVE_level']/text()">INFO</xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Configuration/Properties">
      <!-- copy the Properties element -->
      <xsl:copy>
         <!-- copy and modify the existing content of the Properties element -->
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
         <!-- add Property 6 if it was missing -->
         <xsl:if test="not(Property/@name='6')">
           <Property name="6">abc</Property>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For brevity, when creating Property 6, I changed your `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute` to use a literal XML element instead.